# Access S3 from Lambda within VPC using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "api" {
  function_name = "ApiController"

  timeout = 10

  s3_bucket = "mn-lambda"
  s3_key = "mn/v1.0.0/sketch-avatar-api-1.0.0-all.jar"

  handler = "io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaHandler"
  runtime = "java11"

  memory_size = 1024

  role = aws_iam_role.api_lambda.arn

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.lambda.id]
    subnet_ids = [for subnet in aws_subnet.private: subnet.id]
  }
}
```

Within a VPC

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr_block
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}
```

I created a aws_vpc_endpoint because I read that's what's need for my VPC to access S3

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.region}.s3"
}
```

I created and attached a policy allowing access to S3

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "s3" {
  role = aws_iam_role.api_lambda.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = ["*"]

    actions = [
      "s3:*",
    ]
  }
}
```

It might be worth noting that the buckets I'm trying to access is created using the aws cli but in the same region. So not with terraform.

The problem is that my Lambda is timing out when I try to read files from S3.

The full project can be found [here](https://github.com/tonsV2/sketch-avatar-infrastructure) should anyone want to take a peek.

Comment: I guess it's more of a connectivity issue rather than a code issue. Can you read S3 buckets created via the CLI?

Comment: Is the `aws_vpc_endpoint` attached to the VPC's route table?

Comment: You forgot to specify [route_table_ids](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc_endpoint#route_table_ids). S3 is VPC gateway and it must be associated with appropriate route tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating `com.amazonaws.${var.region}.s3` which is [gateway VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) , which shouldn't be confused with [interface VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html).

One of the key differences between the two is that the gateway type **requires association with route tables**. Thus you should use [route_table_ids](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc_endpoint#route_table_ids) to associate your S3 gateway with route tables of your subnets.

For example, to use default main VPC route table:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.region}.s3"

  route_table_ids = [aws_vpc.vpc.main_route_table_id]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [aws_vpc_endpoint_route_table_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc_endpoint_route_table_association) to do it as well.